# How to use PIVOT here?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, pivot, sum

I have this table

```
+--------+--------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+
|  XPK   | First_count  |  First_amount  | Second_count |  Second_amount |
+--------+--------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+
|      1 |     10       |       2000     |     20       |       5000     | 
+--------+--------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Need to get result like this, sum and pivot:

```
+-------------+------------+
|Total_count  |     30     |
|Total_amount |    7000    |
+-------------+------------+
```

I need to use pivot, but how?

Using MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: Did you try anything? Read the documentation for pivot? Google?

Comment: Yes. Trying but for now, I don't have solution...

Comment: okay, great, post what you've tried so far.

Comment: First, get simple table with query: 

if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#tps_pivot') is not null drop table #tps_pivot
select 
 [total cnt] = SUM(tps.first_count) + SUM(tps.second_count)
 ,[total amnt] =SUM(tps.first_amount) + SUM(tps.second_amount)
into #tps_pivot
from tps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, for such need, I would not use `pivot`, I would simply:

```
select XPK, 'Total_count', First_count + Second_count
from my_table
union
select XPK, 'Total_amount', First_amount + Second_amount
from my_table
```

If you really want to use `pivot` you can try:

```
select XPK, kpi, total
from (
select XPK,  First_count + Second_count as Total_count, First_amount + Second_amount as Total_amount
from my_table
) t
unpivot (total for kpi in(Total_count, Total_amount)) tt
```

But maybe your problem is more complex than what you described....

Comment: No, this works like charm. Thanks a lot !!!